# Exporting HTML div content as pdf with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I want to export selected div as a PDF. That div contains text, images and some charts.

```
<div id="newdiv">
    <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
    <p>A Paragraph A Paragraph A Paragraph A Paragraph</p>
</div>
<button type="button">click</button>
```

with all CSS properties

Answer (score 0):

You will need a plugin such as:

- https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF
- https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

I will cite this awesome [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/) to show you how it can be done. Below I past the code that I am referencing from this fiddle.

```
//HTML
    <div id="content">
         <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

        <p>a pararaph</p>
    </div>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>


//jQuery  
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

   $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Alejandra, this is good but I want to export with images.with this code, I'm unable to export the images.Can you give one example with text and images.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not sure if exporting images is supported like that w/ this plugin...hmm. What about this other one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf  This one even seems to support the images, based on the GitHub issues I saw here: https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/44